# which v.clean option is required to eliminate overlapping segments of lines?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I want to produce a polygon layer out of lines like in this image with the command `poligonize`:

[image]
Source: [QGIS create boundaries from background image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281041/qgis-create-boundaries-from-background-image/281058#281058)

The problem is that some of the lines are coming from polygons with the command `polygon to line` tool in QGIS like in this image:

[image]
Source: [How to merge overlapping and duplicate lines from vector layer to one single line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/how-to-merge-overlapping-and-duplicate-lines-from-vector-layer-to-one-single-lin)

I am struggling to understand which options I should use in `v.clean` to remove the overlapping segments of the line layer, or which other stepts or tools I could use to get the desired output in a straight way.

The main asumption is that lines match exactly.

My software QGIS 2.18 and GRASS 7.4

Comment: I found a related question, but the solution was not done in QGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236903/converting-polygon-to-lines-without-duplicate-edges?rq=1

Comment: I cannot understand what do you want to do? Do you want to remove duplicates?Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get v.clean to remove duplicates in the way I was expecting using rmdupl (or the -c option*). However, the QGIS algorithm "Delete duplicate geometries" works well. Steps:

- Break lines at intersections with v.clean's "break";
  [image]
- Remove duplicates with "Delete duplicate geometries".
  [image]
- Create the new polygons with "Polygonize"
  [image]

These could be chained with a single [Processing model](https://gist.github.com/simbamangu/16b63a57a10566f5118b8f8f3bd7c24b#file-poly2lines_rmdup_2poly-model3) (click for gist of a model file).

[image: Input polygon -> lines -> break -> remove duplicates -> polygon]

*The 'recommended followup tools' in the dialog adds the `-c` option. From the help: *Hint: Breaking lines should be followed by removing duplicates, e.g. v.clean ... tool=break,rmdupl. If the -c flag is used with v.clean ... tool=break, duplicates are automatically removed.* Not working in this case for some reason.

Comment: "These could be chained with a single Processing model". That will be impressive! I have never been in the processing model yet, nice idea for the next question

Comment: I'm on QGIS 3.0 / Ubuntu 16.04 and the model builder dialog is not working but will add that when I get a chance. Thanks for screenshots, didn't have enough time to add workflow.

Comment: However - I'd point out that 'Polygonize' was not your core question - I have not tested that last step and may remove it here.

Comment: polygonize was the main goal (first line of my question) and I have tested it, that's why I marked as solved, because it works

Comment: I've added a link to a processing model - may not work in 2.18 but you can see the steps I've added in the image, should be reproducible.